# Guessing game, no data passing to another form

Tags: php

I am working on a guessing game. The guessing code is working, however, when i want to click the 'give up' to display the number, is not passing the value to the give up. My apology, I am fairly new with php.

Any suggestion or hint how this could be done?

below is the guessinggame.php and the bottom one is the giveup.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$number = rand(1,100);

if(isset($_POST["guess"])){
    $guess  = $_POST['guess'];
    $number  = $_POST['number'];
    $display = $_POST['submit'];

    if ($guess < $number){ 
        echo "The number needs to be higer!";
    }else
    if($guess > $number){       
        echo "The number needs to be lower!";
    }else
    if($guess == $number){      
        echo "Congratulation! You Guessed the hidden number.";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Guess A Number</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="guess-a-number">
    <label for="guess"><h1>Guess a Number:</h1></label><br/ >
    <input type="text" name="guess" />
    <input name="number" type="hidden" value="<?= $number ?>" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" />
    <br/ >
    <a href="giveup.php">Give Up</a> 
    <br/ >
    <a href="startover.php">Start Over</a> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

giveup.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Guess A Number</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="guessinggame.php" method="GET" name="guess-a-number">
    <?php echo "<br />The hidden number is:".$number."<br />";?>
    <br/ >
    <a href="startover.php">Start Over</a> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you click on giveup.php, it just contains a form... nothing is submitted to the PHP processing code on guessinggame.php, so you don't get anything.

Comment: You start a session, but don't actually use it, use the session to store the variables instead of storing them in the form, this way people can't cheat by looking at the form as well.

Comment: @shamil Yes, that is true, however, any hint what sort of code to be consider to use?

Comment: @TylerMatema You could have it as a separate form, going back to the same page with some other processing, if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the number in the user session in your main script:

```
session_start();
$number = rand(1,100);
$_SESSION['number'] = $number;
```

Then, retrieve it in `giveup.php`:

```
$number = $_SESSION['number'];
```

Comment: Thanks Madbreaks, that was helpful!! Btw, do you know any suggestion on how to generate how many times user guessed?

Comment: Sure. If `$_POST` not set, set `$_SESSION['guesses']` to 0.  Then each time they guess, increment the session var.